# How to store this kind of data in an array

Tags: c

The input consists of multiple lines.
The first line contains a number n which indicates that the number of rows in the Pascal’s triangle will be n+1.
The second line contains a number m which indicates the number of transactions to be performed on the Pascal’s triangle. Each transaction is given in a separate line. A transaction is a space separated list of integers. The first integer in each list indicates the row number, say R, and the rest of the integers in the list indicate the indices of values in row R. For each transaction, you have to compute the sum of given coefficients in the given row R.
Example: Input will be given in the following format:

```
5
3
3 1 2
5 1 1 1 4
4 2 3 2
```

what should be done to store the values of transition lines like

```
3 1 2
5 1 1 1 4
4 2 3 2
```

under a single array variable.So that it can be passed to a function completely.

Comment: Have you tried anything, anything?

Comment: actually my complete program is to print the sum of the selected coefficients.. like 3c1+3c2=6.. i tried it using a new array to every new line with termination of a delimiter '\n' but it is not getting done..

Comment: i am passing new array to the function that returns the sum of the selected coefficients.. but my program needs sum of individual transition line to print as follows as 6 20 16..

Comment: post the code please, and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Click edit, copy the code and paste it, try to format it, indenting it properly so it's readable, blocks of code should be indented with for spaces, and then your own indentation is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply adds all the transactions for a line using recursive function.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int add_transaction(int *contents,int size)
{
   if(!size)
     return 0;
   return (*contents + add_transaction(contents+1,size-1));

}

void main()
{

  int size;             //The no of lines
  int* no_transaction;  //To store no of transactions of each line
  int** contents;       //To store contents of each line. No of contents in line determined by transaction[i]

  int c1,c2;
  printf("Give size of triangle :");
  scanf("%d",&size);

  no_transaction=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (size+1));
  contents=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size+1));
  for(c1=0;c1<=size;c1++)
  {
     printf("\nGive no of transaction for line no %d :",c1+1);
     scanf("%d",no_transaction+c1);
     contents[c1]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*no_transaction[c1]);
     for(c2=0;c2<no_transaction[c1];c2++)
     {
        printf("\tFor line %d give transaction no %d :",c1+1,c2+1);
        scanf("%d",contents[c1]+c2);
     }
  }
  printf("\nThe sum of the series is :");
  for(c1=0;c1<=size;c1++)
  {
     if(c1)
      printf("+ %d ",add_transaction(contents[c1],no_transaction[c1]));
     else
      printf(" %d",add_transaction(contents[c1],no_transaction[c1]));
  }

 //Code to free the allocated memory.
}
```

Comment: you can make a larger array and end the transactions for a line when user gives 0 as no, of transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a structure like this you might be able to do what you are trying to do. You can pass structure to function to compute sum of each line.

```
struct pascaltirangle
{
  int size;          //The no of lines
  int* no_transactions; //To store no of transactions of each line
  int** contents;    //To store contents of each line. No of contents in line determined by transaction[i]
} dat;

//code to take input of size

dat.no_transactions=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (dat.size+1));

//code to take no of transaction for each line

for(int i=0;i<=dat.size;i++)
    contents[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*dat.no_transaction[i]);      

//code to take input for contents[i][j]
```